# how to read a histogram from a file in r?

Tags: r, statistics, histogram

There is plenty of resources about how to calculate a histogram in R. However, I couldn't find anything explaining how to read a ready histogram from a file.
For example, I have a text file:

```
5 0.00413341649086988
15 0.00751482028214599
25 0.00896480849895891
...
```

where the first column is the breaks, the beginning of the binning intervals, and the second column is the probability of having an event at that bin.
If I do:

```
d <- read.table("input.txt")
```

I get an error whenever I use `mean(d)`, because of course R doesn't know that the two columns of d are actually a histogram. 
I'd like to translate that into a histogram just for the convenience of calculating easily mean, std deviation, ecc....
Otherwise, I should do something like `sum(d$V1*d$V2)` for the mean, `sqrt(sum((d$V1^2)*d$V2) - (sum(d$V1*d$V2))^2)` for the standard deviation, and so forth.

Comment: What do you mean by "translate into histogram"? R doesn't exactly have special functions for dealing with histograms, aside from plotting them

Comment: If I write `h <- hist(...)`, `h` is a histogram that R can deal with (not only plotting, but also distinguishing counts from density, statistics, etc.). How can I create an object like `h` with data from a text file?

Comment: Classes in R are just lists with a special `class` attribute. The `hist` class in R needs vectors for `breaks`, `counts`, `density`, and `mids`. You have breaks and density, but you're missing the counts (you can gets `mids` from the breaks attribute). As it stands, you need to provide the counts. Your text file just doesn't have enough information.

Comment: Oh I see, and what if I had a 3rd column with counts? How could I initialize a `hist` then?

Answer (score 2):

If your text file looks like this:

```
"breaks" "dens" "counts"
"1" 0 0.75 3
"2" 0.2 1.25 5
"3" 0.4 1.5 6
"4" 0.6 0.75 3
"5" 0.8 0.75 3
```

You can create a histogram object by putting the relevant vectors into a list, then assigning its class attribute. Here is an example of a function that does that:

```
make_hist <- function(df){
  his <- list()
  binwidth <- df$breaks[2]-df$breaks[1]
  # Assinging the breaks. Note that the last break is missing from the text file so we must add it
  his$breaks <- c(df$breaks, df$breaks[length(df$breaks)]+binwidth)
  his$counts <- df$counts
  his$density <- df$density
  his$mids <- df$breaks + binwidth/2
  his$xname <- deparse(substitute(df))
  his$equidist <- TRUE
  class(his) <- "histogram"
  return(his)
}
```

The resulting object will behave like an object created with `histogram()`, for instance when calling `plot(make_hist(his_txt))`